# jOOQ H2 Case sensitivity issues without codegen

Tags: java, mysql, relational-database, h2, jooq

I've been using H2 on the functional tests part of a MySQL based application with Hibernate. I was finally fed up with it and I decided to usq jOOQ mostly so I could still abstract myself from the underlying database.

My problem is that I don't like this code generation thing jOOQ does at all since I'm yet to see an example with it properly set up in multiple profiles, also don't like connecting to the database as part of my build. It's overall quite a nasty set-up I don't want to spend a morning doing to realise is very horrible and I don't want it in the project.

I'm using tableByName() and fieldByName() instead which I thought was a good solution, but I'm getting problems with H2 putting everything in uppercase.

If I do something like `Query deleteInclusiveQuery = jooqContext.delete(tableByName("inclusive_test"))...` I get table inclusive_test not found. Note this has nothing to do with the connection delay or closing configuration.

I tried changing the connection to use `;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false` but then I get field not found (I thought it would translate all schema).

I'm not sure if H2 is either unable to create non-upper cased schemas or I'm failing at that. If the former then I'd expect jOOQ to also upper case the table and field names in the query.

example output is:
`delete from "inclusive_test" where "segment_id" in (select "id" from "segment" where "external_taxonomy_id" = 1)`
which would be correct if H2 schema would have not been created like this, however the query I'm creating the schema with specifically puts it in lowercase, yet in the end it ends up being upper cased, which Hibernate seems to understand or solve, but not jOOQ

Anyway, I'm asking if there is a solution because I'm quite disappointed at the moment and I'm considering just dropping the tests where I can't use Hibernate.

Any solution that is not using the code generation feature is welcome.

Comment: I think we would need a simple, complete, reproducible test case.

Comment: yeh, unfortunately my case is not a simple one, I'd have to produce it, bottom line is, using raw prepared statements will not work with H2 (unless you manage to lower case the schema), jOOQ seems to do the trick if you use AS_IS setting or you set database_to_upper=false... I'm not quite confident I understand if the driver, jOOQ, the schema or who is upper and lower casing which thing... I think it quite silly they thought to upper case anything in the first place :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My problem is that I don't like this code generation thing jOOQ does at all since I'm yet to see an example with it properly set up in multiple profiles, also don't like connecting to the database as part of my build. It's overall quite a nasty set-up I don't to spend a morning doing to realise is very horrible and I don't want it in the project.

You're missing out on a ton of awesome jOOQ features if you're going this way. See this very interesting discussion about the rationale of why having a DB-connection in the build isn't that bad:

- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jooq-user/kQO757qJPbE/UszW4aUODdQJ

In any case, don't get frustrated too quickly. There are a couple of reasons why things have been done the way they are. [`DSL.fieldByName()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#fieldByName%28java.lang.String...%29) creates a case-sensitive column. If you provide a lower-case `"inclusive_test"` column, then jOOQ will render the name with quotes and in lower case, by default.

You have several options:

1. Consistently name your MySQL and H2 tables / columns, explicitly specifying the case. E.g. `` `inclusive_test` `` in MySQL and `"inclusive_test"` in H2.
2. Use [jOOQ's Settings](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/) to override the rendering behaviour. As I said, by default, jOOQ renders everything with quotes. You can override this by specifying [`RenderNameStyle.AS_IS`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/conf/RenderNameStyle.html#AS_IS)
3. Use [`DSL.field()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field%28java.lang.String%29) instead of `DSL.fieldByName()` instead. It will allow you to keep full control of your SQL string.

By the way, I think we'll change the manual to suggest using `DSL.field()` instead of `DSL.fieldByName()` to new users. This whole case-sensitivity has been causing too many issues in the past. This will be done with [Issue #3218](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3218)

Comment: I'm explicitly specifying the lower case name for the table in H2, I think maybe the driver is upper casing everything. I'm using the spring jdbc:initialize thing. The thing about database connections on builds is at least in my company the builds happen quite agnostically in a random jenkins box which will not have specific configurations or connections. I don't like the idea of configuration being required for building. e.g. migrations, and all other stuff like this are done via external deploy scripts, not in maven... I'll keep trying with your suggestions and come back

Comment: @fd8s0: Another option ([mentioned in this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jooq-user/kQO757qJPbE/UszW4aUODdQJ)) is to build and check in database metadata libraries in a separate environment. It would really be too bad to remove all those great features just because of build infrastructure... But anyway, that's not the issue here. [Have you logged your SQL output yet?](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/logging/) Is it rendering the correct casing?

Comment: I added some more stuff to the question, I'm not entirely sure jOOQ is at fault here. I don't quite follow why H2 upper cases everything.

Comment: using renderNameStyle AS_IS passes through the table name but gets me `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "NAME" not found; SQL statement:
insert into segment (`name`) values (?)` which is the same I got when I was trying ;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false, I'm not going to try to understand why... since AS_IS suggests it should keep the query lower cased which is what was happening before?

Comment: OK, it was worth a try. Back to @ThomasMueller, then

Comment: ah no!! wait, that's good, that error is from a raw query not coming from jOOQ, it seems like that works... same as DATABASE_TO_UPPER would have worked too, as long as I use jOOQ for all queries